# Rasterize right method for true value of point grid?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation

Is rasterize an interpolation or does it just burn in the "true" value of the point? I have a grided data that is evenly spaced and dense. I would like to just have a raster with the "real" value of the point grid and where there is no value it should be Nodata. Is this the method to go if I only whant the values of the point?

Comment: Okej. I will edit it.

Comment: I use GDAL->Grid (Linear) for evenly spaced magnetometry data. You should play with the parameters 'RADIUS_1' and        'RADIUS_2' and set them to the distance between your datapoints

Comment: Thank you. I will try using it. Do you know if my question is right?

Comment: I did understand your question, so the question should be ok...